# SQL UDF speed in subquery vs in declare

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, user-defined-functions

1. I've created an UDF that get the last business day and it runs in less than 1s.

```
SELECT BlackWidow.dbo.LastBusinessDay('2015-12-31',DEFAULT)
```

2. I've also created an UDF that returns a table and it runs in 1s.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  BlackWidow.dbo.TurnoverTradesMarketCapCountry ('2015-12-31', 50, 20, 50, 100000, 1000000000, 3, 'Brazil')
```

3. When I run both together it tooks more than a minute to run

```
SELECT * 
FROM  BlackWidow.dbo.TurnoverTradesMarketCapCountry (BlackWidow.dbo.LastBusinessDay('2015-12-31',DEFAULT), 50, 20, 50, 100000, 1000000000, 3, 'Brazil')
```

4. If I run a code like the below, it only took 1s

```
DECLARE @date as DATETIME

SET @date=BlackWidow.dbo.LastBusinessDay('2015-12-31',DEFAULT)

SELECT * 
FROM  BlackWidow.dbo.TurnoverTradesMarketCapCountry (@date, 50, 20, 50, 100000, 1000000000, 3, 'Brazil')
```

Any suggestion why it took so many more time in case 3 than in case 4?

Comment: SQL does a significant amount of optimizing behind the scenes. It likely allowed additional optimizing by taking the function out of the params. As now, it has a hard value to work off of.

Comment: What are the two execution plans?

Comment: In scenario 3 the scalar UDF would cause RBAR, and probably some other performance issues. - [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for the performance difference is that the query optimizer in SQL Server is unable to correctly estimate the query cost in the first query. The optimizer does not know what the return of the function will be ahead of time so it is unable to estimate an appropriate cost for the query before execution. This limitation means that extremely poor query plans may be chosen for execution.

The second query is much easier for the optimizer to evaluate because once the @date variable is assigned the query optimizer is able to cost the query execution in a more economic fashion.

These operations of functionally the same, but they are not literally the same when it comes to execution by SQL Server. To confirm you can look at the estimated query execution and look at the differences in estimated cost by the SQL optimizer. Then run the queries and look at the actual execution plans. They will not be the same even though functionally they accomplish the same things.

Comment: The query that the OP says performs best uses a *variable* - values of variables are not sniffed (unless using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`